# Does curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, msg_out); duplicate memory?

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I m using many times

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, msg_out);
```

in my code before I m cleaning with `curl_easy_cleanup()` functions.

Does CURL make a memory copy (dynamic memory) of the `msg_out` in his environment ?

Comment: Was this really that hard to find in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not make a copy by default, and this is stated in the [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html):

> The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it must be preserved by the calling application until the associated transfer finishes. This behaviour can be changed (so libcurl does copy the data) by setting the [CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html) option.

Comment: So as I expected you could manipulate the behavior, and although **not** copying by default is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

If it does or not, is irrelevant, just do `curl_easy_cleanup()` at the end and it should be good.

Most likely it does copy post fields, so it's safe to `free()` them after you passed them to the function, otherwise it would not be possible to guarantee the success of `curl_easy_perform()`, if I was a curl library programmer I would copy them, because the `curl` handle is an opaque structure, and I don't want the library user messing with it, so copy seems like the right choice.